# Objective-C: C Macros Naming Conventions

Tags: objective-c, c, macros, naming-conventions

In "Advances in Objective-C" of the WWDC 2013 Session Videos, Doug Gregor suggests using "prefixed, very-long, uppercased" names for C macros.

But, the slide says `UPPERCASE_MACRO_NAMES`, which doesn't seem to include a prefix.

Should I prefix C macros with my class prefix?

Answer (score 2):

If you've enabled Objective-C modules, you should be OK using names without a prefix and of any length. I recommend using `ALL_CAPS` because it's very conventional and distinguishes C macros from class names, string constants, etc. I also recommend prefixing, with the class prefix, global macros (ones you might define in `XXXDefines.h`, where `XXX` is your class prefix, or any other .h file). This helps distinguish them from local macros, those defined in .m files. Local macros names shouldn't be prefixed with the class prefix.